# How to get a full sentence from user input and run it through a for loop to then output on terminal

Tags: c++

I'm practicing using vectors and arrays and seeing the difference between both. I accomplished this program using vectors and an array. So far I can get the program to do what I want it to do, that is until I include user input. The program will read the first word of the sentence but omit the rest. I did some research and have tried including cin.getline() before the first for loop, but that didn't work. I tried other getline methods like pre setting the value at zero but I end up getting lost with a bunch of errors, or it outputs only part of the sentence.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string input = "turpentine and turtles";
    char vowels\[] ={ 'a', 'e', 'i','o', 'u' };

    for (int i=0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (input[i] == vowels[j]{
            cout << input[i]; }
        }
        if (input[i] == 'e') {
            cout << input[i];
        }
        if (input[i] == 'u') {
            cout << input[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: std::getline(std::cin, input); reads a full line of input into the string variable named input

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You want to read a sentence into a `string`, is that correct? Show us your attempt to do that; write a program that reads a sentence and the prints it out, and don't attempt iteration and vowel-hunting until the reading works.

Comment: god, it was that simple. I was over complicating it.. thank you gerum!

Answer (score 0):

I solve your code to print vowels characters in the input sentence

```
string input = "turpentine and turtles";
char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        if(input[i] == vowels[j])
        {
            cout << input[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline` to read in the line provided by the user.

There are several build-breaking typos in your code, which I've fixed below.

Also, it's in your best interest to avoid `using namespace std;` - [it's rarely worth the trouble it can cause](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/naming-collisions-and-an-introduction-to-namespaces/).

Remember your includes for `<string>`, et al as well.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto vowels = std::vector{ 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    auto input = std::string();
    //auto input = std::string("turpentine and turtles");

    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        if (vowels.contains(input[i])) {
            std::cout << input[i] << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```